# sort results by column not row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

is it possible in SQL to sort by column and not by row? i do not need a basic ORDER BY statement, i know how those work (ie: order by column1, column2, etc).

basically trying to sort something like this:

```
column 1    column 2    column 3
   1            0           3
```

trying to sort to this:

```
column 3    column 1    column 2
   3           1           0
```

Is this even possible in SQL? preferably t-sql or anything that will run on sql server 2005

ive been searching online for hours on this and no one even seems to want to ask this question. or i suck at searching.

```
   ; with numbered as
   (
     select SUM(OrderReceived) as c1, SUM(OrderOnHold) as c2, SUM(OrderConfirmed) as     c3,
     row_number() over (order by employee) RecordNumber
     from( SELECT 


e.FirstName+' '+e.LastName AS Employee
,CASE WHEN oim.MilestoneID = 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as OrderReceived
,CASE WHEN oim.MilestoneID = 15 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as OrderOnHold
,CASE WHEN oim.MilestoneID = 20 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as OrderConfirmed
FROM OrderItems oi
    JOIN Orders o on o.orderid = oi.orderid
    JOIN OrderItemMilestones oim on oim.orderid = oi.orderid and oim.orderitemid     =     oi.orderitemid
    JOIN Milestones m on m.milestoneid = oim.milestoneid
    JOIN Employees e on e.username = oim.recordedbyuser
    JOIN Clients cl on cl.clientid = o.clientid
WHERE oim.MilestoneDate Between '2012-08-01' and '2012-08-05'
    and e.terminationdate is null
),

ordered as
(
 select SUM(OrderReceived) as c1, SUM(OrderOnHold) as c2, SUM(OrderConfirmed) as c3,
         row_number() over (partition by RecordNumber
                           order by employee desc) rn
    from numbered

  unpivot (v for c in (c1, c2, c3)) u
)
select RecordNumber,
     [1] c1,
     [2] c2,
     [3] c3
 from 
 (
 select RecordNumber,
         v,
         Rn
    from ordered
  ) o
 pivot (min(employee) for Rn in ([1], [2], [3])) p
```

Comment: Are you taking about column reordering? And if your answer is **yes**, are you taking about column reordering per row so each row has a different column order according to their values?

Comment: What happens when your SQL returns more than one row?? What do you expect?

Comment: sorry about the delayed response, stuck at a desk all day and cant check this a lot

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is relatively simple way to sort columns. If you first [unpivot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.90%29.aspx), sort and [pivot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) your data, you will get sorted columns.

[Here is Sql Fiddle with example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6d442/12).

```
-- Assign arbitrary numbers to records
-- You might skip this part if you have unique column
-- in which case you should replace RecordNumber with this ID
; with numbered as
(
  select *,
         row_number() over (order by (select null)) RecordNumber
    from test
),
-- Generate order by
-- For all the columns in record.
-- Rn will always be in range
-- 1..NumberOfColumns
-- Order is done on unpivoted data
ordered as
(
  select *,
         row_number() over (partition by RecordNumber
                            order by v desc) rn
    from numbered
 -- list all the columns here
 -- v is for value
 -- c is for column
 unpivot (v for c in (c1, c2, c3)) u
)
-- Finally return the data in original layout
select RecordNumber,
       [1] c1,
       [2] c2,
       [3] c3
  from 
  (
    -- Only the columns needed by the query
    -- Pivot will not play nice even if you
    -- Select only subset of columns in
    -- outer query
    select RecordNumber,
           v,
           Rn
      from ordered
  ) o
 -- Get value for row numbers 1..NumberOfColumns
 pivot (min(v) for Rn in ([1], [2], [3])) p
```

You might want to add header rows so you would know which value come from which column. To do this I would add a column identifying header/row, union all to `o` to get corresponding headers and order by which would ensure that these two rows stay together:

```
  (
    select RecordNumber,
           v,
           Rn,
           1 HdrRow
      from ordered
     union all
    select RecordNumber,
           c,    -- Column name is in c
           Rn,
           0 HdrRow
      from ordered
  ) o
    ...
  order by RecordNumber, HdrRow
```

Comment: this is pretty advanced for me but thank you very much, i can sort of see how it works but i just got introduced to pivot and over commands, so im still very unfamiliar.  thanks again ill do my best to implement this

Comment: @wondergoat77 Replace c1, c2, and c3 with your columns and add your select list to both inner and outer query in `Finally return ...` section. This should be all, apart from actual table name.

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović thanks for the assistance, im going to try this out this afternoon at work to see if can get it working.

Comment: i think i have this close to working but am getting a syntax error (Incorrect syntax near ',') referring to  ), ordered as section

Comment: its pretty long so it will probably be split up in a couple comments, ive also hit a roadblock, my VPN to the database i need is not working so i cannot test this to even see if its working now.

Comment: this will be an abbreviated version but there are about 30 columns each like the SUM(columnname) as column and those are linked to the case statement to get the quantity per each column

Comment: SELECT 
 Team
 ,Employee
 ,SUM(OrderReceived) as OrderReceived
 ,SUM(OrderOnHold) as OrderOnHold FROM(
SELECT CASE
 
  WHEN oim.RecordedByUser in ('mchennault','jbell','rmurray','jwilliams','lbates','vbains')
   THEN 'Operations Team'
  
  ELSE 'Uncatagorized'
  END AS Team
 ,e.FirstName+' '+e.LastName AS Employee, CASE WHEN oim.MilestoneID = 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as OrderReceived
 ,CASE WHEN oim.MilestoneID = 15 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as OrderOnHold FROM OrderItems oi
 JOIN Orders o on o.orderid = oi.orderid
 JOIN OrderItemMilestones oim on oim.orderid = oi.orderid and oim.orderitemid =

Comment: oi.orderitemid
 JOIN Milestones m on m.milestoneid = oim.milestoneid
 JOIN Employees e on e.username = oim.recordedbyuser
 JOIN Clients cl on cl.clientid = o.clientid
WHERE oim.MilestoneDate Between '2012-08-01' and '2012-08-05'
 and e.terminationdate is null
 )x
WHERE team = 'operations team'
GROUP BY Team, Employee
ORDER BY Team, Employee

Comment: Hi @wondergoat77, sorry for the delay. I've seen the query. I thought that you had syntax error regarding unpivot/pivot query.

Comment: sorry, that was my original query, i cannot post right now but will come back later today to post it

Comment: so sorry about the delay, i have put the query i am having trouble with up in my original post above.

Comment: @wondergoat77 Add `a)` before comma. The thing is, derived table in `from` needs an alias (a) and cte has to be closed with `)`.

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović thanks for that, i didnt notice the CTE wasnt closed. now i have a new error and i cant figure out where to put the fix.  Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'a.Employee' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović the most logical place i can think to put it would be right after )a but that makes another error when i do so. Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 26
Invalid column name 'OrderReceived'.  - this error is returned for all named columns not just this one.

Comment: @wondergoat77 [Please see this Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ab850/1). I've added employee to select/group by list. Since RecordNumber was introduced only to serve as id for a row, and employee can serve the same purpose, I've removed RecordNumber and used employee. I've also fixed select list and order by in `ordered`.

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović thanks so much again for the help, this did the trick.  Ill just need to add in a few more things to the query for my end purpose but this was the biggest obstacle.  Thanks again.

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović i was working with this and just noticed something that basically makes all of this more or less useless to me.  I need to column headers/names to carry with the values as well. right now i get the same column headers regardless of the values so i cant tell which values go with which columns. Is there any way to make the query do that?

Comment: @wondergoat77 i'm not sure. Would you like headers next to values or above? It is going to be very ugly either way.

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović i assumed so lol, its already a beast to me.  Would want the headers above though.  Thanks again for all the help.

Comment: @wondergoat77 Please take a look at [this Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/22186/1). You will notice `HdrRow` column and union all in `o`. This adds headers for each row by selecting `c`. HdrRow is used to distinguish between header and data row. I've used it to assertain that both rows stay together (see order by). Because of union all I had to cast your numbers to varchars; hopefully this will not be a problem.

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović you are truly a genius! thank you for all the help! this works great for what i need.  You have taught me a lot working through this problem.

Answer (score 5):

Are you using `SELECT *`? If so, stop doing that. If you know you want them listed that way, then write:

```
SELECT [column 3], [column 1], [column 2] FROM dbo.table;
```

If you mean you want to sort within those columns, I'm not sure how meaningful that would be. But I guess you could do something like:

```
DECLARE @x TABLE(c1 INT, c2 INT, c3 INT);

INSERT @x(c1,c2,c3) SELECT 2,1,3
UNION ALL SELECT 3,4,5
UNION ALL SELECT 5,4,3
UNION ALL SELECT 3,1,2
UNION ALL SELECT 3,3,3
UNION ALL SELECT 3,4,3
UNION ALL SELECT 4,3,4;

SELECT c1 = CASE
  WHEN c1 >= c2 AND c1 >= c3 THEN c1
  WHEN c2 >= c1 AND c2 >= c3 THEN c2
  ELSE c3 END,
c2 = CASE 
  WHEN c1 >= c2 AND c1 >= c3 THEN 
    CASE WHEN c2 >= c3 THEN c2 ELSE c3 END
  WHEN c2 >= c1 AND c2 >= c3 THEN
    CASE WHEN c1 >= c3 THEN c1 ELSE c3 END
  ELSE
    CASE WHEN c1 >= c2 THEN c1 ELSE c2 END
  END,
c3 = CASE
  WHEN c1 <= c2 AND c1 <= c3 THEN c1
  WHEN c2 <= c1 AND c2 <= c3 THEN c2
  ELSE c3 END
FROM @x;
```

Results:

```
c1   c2   c3
---- ---- ----
3    2    1
5    4    3
5    4    3
3    2    1
3    3    3
4    3    3
4    4    3
```

Comment: I suppose this is too trivial for the OP and I'm almost sure they're not after this... But even though result query would only return a single row of records, this wouldn't work since they want them ordered as per their values, and not as a statically defined list of columns that is always the same. No matter how you order them in your query, they will return in that order regardless of their values.

Comment: @RobertKoritnik you might be right, you might not. Who knows? The OP hasn't bothered to clarify. In the meantime I'll err on the side of simplicity. If you want to propose the other answer, go nuts.

Comment: I'm not feeling that very olympic today @AaronBertrand... ;)

Comment: hi, this will not work for what i need, i cannot define the columns like this, i need them to populate in a numerical order without me needing to define the columns manually. please let me know what other info i can provide, sorry about the slower responses, im at work right now trying to figure some other stuff out too. thanks for all the help

Comment: thanks for the example, im still a bit new to SQL so ill need to play around and see if i can get it working for what i need but it definitely put me on the right track, much appreciated.

Comment: Of course if you add a 4th column the complexity explodes exponentially. You would be much better off sorting the data *before* storage, e.g. in your application code.

Comment: wish i had that control, but i dont. i only have access to the tables in the databse and cannot edit a single one, cant even create a table.  great idea though, problem is i have about 30 columns to deal with so that code would be ridiculous i assume

Comment: Yep, seems like a case where design is not going to be able to satisfy requirements very easily. Is there a key in the table at least?

Comment: yes, 4 FK actually but no PK.  the table consists of orderid, orderitemid, milestoneid, milestonedate, recordedbyuser.. all FK except the date

Answer (score 0):

### Double query with dynamic query

If your query only returns a single row, then you can go about this problem by executing a query two times:

1. Query your data to get values of columns
   a) **And** generate dynamic SQL with column order as per their values from result
2. Execute dynamic query

If your query should return several rows of data I suppose we're going to need some more information what you're trying to achieve to come up with a feasible solution or at least a better suggestion how to mitigate your problem.

Comment: sorry if i wasnt thorough enough, i do need more than 1 row returned. thought there might be a simple explanation i just didnt know in SQL yet.  im basically trying to sum up employee productivity.  i have the query returning column1 for the employee name, and every other column is a status in our internal system, i am then counting each of the status's per employee and getting my results.  the results are similar to my first example.  you should probably know that the columns are created by defining each column using CASE and SUM() to define and count each status.  this may be

Comment: where i am running into the problem, since my columns are all defined already, then they may not be rearrangable, hope that was enough info, let me know if you need more.

Comment: reading your idea it does seem like it would work, could you post an example of what you stated above in SQL?

Comment: It does shed some light ony the problem at hand... But still not enough. It would be great if you could provide a few rows of our table (make them up). And then provide results based on that data... I'm not sure whether you want **a** preserve first column (name) and sum up values of all other columns or **b** preserve first column, sum up all others and transpose rows to columns so each column has the name of a person and value which is the sum of al statuses.

Comment: ill do my best but im a little new at this so bear with the newbie at SQL and forums please, will put in my next comment

Comment: i started with 1 table, from table 1 pulling a column that shows updates in our system everytime an order is touched by an employee.  each one of those rows returns, ordernumber, user, and status that the user put the order in.  this is the main table im pulling From, i dont know how to paste a table in this otherwise i would sorry.       I am then creating a case statement to statement to count each status then summing that each case into its own defined column using a derived table to lay the columns out all summed up. but im not sure how to reorder these based on their returned values.

Comment: can you give me an example of what a dynamic query to sort by value would look like?