# T-SQL: select by ordered columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like this

```
Date          Desc   Val1   Val2    Val3    Val4    Val5
---------------------------------------------------------
18/04/2018      A     1       3      18       2      24
18/04/2018      B    90      18       2      33      40
18/04/2018      C    12      45      11      22       3
18/04/2018      D    10      33       8      15      12
18/04/2018      E    81      77      24       1      15
```

I need to `SELECT` (in new table or VIEW) ordered ascending by column values, like this:

```
Date    Desc    Val1    Val2    Val3    Val4    Val5
------------------------------------------------------
18/04/2018  A   1   2   3   18  24
18/04/2018  B   2   18  33  40  90
18/04/2018  C   3   11  12  22  45
18/04/2018  D   8   10  12  15  33
18/04/2018  E   1   15  24  77  81
```

Sorting/ordering must be only for columns from Val1 to Val5.

How to make it possible in T-SQL?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sort results by column not row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12100566/sort-results-by-column-not-row)

Comment: I think in general you should not be doing this in SQL.  Why do you need this?

Comment: It is doable in SQL, but rarely makes any sense and often indicates wrong design, wrong solution to the problem, or misunderstanding of the requirements. It's hard to tell which one is the case from the very little details in your question, but I'd say that your table must be normalized and the 5 values must be moved to a separate child table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use *apply* operator first sort the column values from `val1` ... `val5`
and do the conditional aggregation based on *sequence* generated via `row_number()` function

```
select [date], [desc],
       max(case when Seq = 1 then value end) val1,
       max(case when Seq = 2 then value end) val2,
       ...  
from (select [date], [desc], a.*, 
             row_number() over (partition by [date], [desc] order by a.value) Seq
      from table t cross apply (values (val1), (val2).. (val5))a(value)
) tt
group by [date], [desc];
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It is exactly what I needed!